# Question regarding the proof that symmetric matrices with real values have real eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to prove that for all symmetric matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the set of eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I've proved it for $2\times2$ matrices by creating a symmetric matrix with arbitrary constants, $a$, $b$, and $c$, and then showing that the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is non-negative.

The problem here is that the higher the dimensions go, the harder it is to use a root-finding formula. I've tried to prove it using some sort of recursion, but I haven't been able to make any breakthroughs.

I want to see if I can prove it using some different method. Are there certain properties of polynomials that only have real root? If they exist, I'll try to use them in my proof.

PS- I'm not looking for the proof itself.

Comment: This result is part of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) for symmetric matrices. You'll find many proofs of this result online; perhaps this is a better approach than trying to prove the result from scratch.

Comment: Hint: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue and $v$ be the corresponding eigenvector and consider the inner product $\langle v, A v\rangle$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$.